# iOS HTTP Communication setup

Tags: iphone, ios, http

So I am making an app that is supposed to communicate with a webservice via basic HTTP requests.  I spent quite a lot of time yesterday looking online and through the developer documentation not finding a whole lot of useful stuff.  The best I managed to find was the CFNetwork Programming Guide in the iPhone developer docs, but this seemed to be lacking a lot of information and was very confusing.

For example: It tells me how to create requests and responses, deserialize both, but not how to submit requests, or receive responses.   And as for a confusing bit, when creating the response it wants me to provide the status code.  Shouldn't the response already contain that information?

Can someone please help?  I really need to get this done soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iOS native networking support is good, it is much easier to use this library: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use It has several advantages, good documented examples and used by many projects.

Comment: While ASI is no longer supported it is still a functioning library. Nevertheless there are other libraries like RestKit, MKNetworkKit, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to be able to fire HTTP requests off, then I'd have thought using something like the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` and `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:` methods would be a good starting point.

Alternatively, if you want to be able to fire off requests asynchronously, the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class should prove ideal.

Answer (score 0):

We did a bit of a walk through on our blog: [How to consume JSON or XML Web APIs on iPhone smoothly](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/10/15/how-to-consume-json-or-xml-web-apis-on-iphone-smoothly/) It uses the ASIHTTPRequest library which makes things a lot easier.